# In nwjs DOM seems to be empty when accessed from another module

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-webkit, nwjs

I want to use modules in my nwjs app that use `document`, but it seems that they cannot properly access DOM of the main page.
Below you can find a simple test that shows the problem.

I have next files:

`package.json`

```
...
"main": "index.html"
...
```

`index.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container_model_view" class="brd"></div>
    <script>let exports = {};</script>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`main.ts` (compiled into main.js before run)

```
import {getEl} from './mod_test';
console.log(document.getElementById("container_model_view"));
console.log(getEl());
```

`mod_test.ts`

```
export function getEl() {
    return document.getElementById("container_model_view");
}
```

Output:

```
div#container_model_view.brd    //access from main.ts - ok
null                //access from mod_test.ts - fail
```

I found that I can bundle my main.js with rollup or webpack then it will work because the main module and the 'mod_test' module are merged into a single file. But I don't like that approach as I afraid it would impact the performance, not to mention it seems to be really unnecessary additional step in the assembling.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, `document` pointing to the main page of the app exists only in browser context. `require()` loads modules in node context. Apparently, there's no way to specify in what context you want to load your module, it always will be node. Some ways to stay in browser context while loading module are described in the [docs](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/JavaScript%20Contexts%20in%20NW.js/#browser-context) as follow:

> Scripts loaded or embedded by traditional web ways, such as using
>   `<script>` element or jQuery’s `$.getScript()` or RequireJS, are running
>   in browser context.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to use any of the above natively with typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Try mixing your contexts, so you can access DOM elements from server context:

**Type this in package.json:**

```
"chromium-args": "--mixed-context"
```